# What is a nice way to optimize mysql query?

Tags: mysql, optimization

here is my very first question...

I have a table... "positions"

and corresponding to every row in this table there is one row in another table "calcPositions".

So this (positions.getNumberOfRows == calcPositions.getNumberOfRows) is true.

And whenever I want to change something in "position" I need to update a "calcPositions" table..

That's why I created a procedure: "calcPositionsUpdate".

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS calcPositionsUpdate;
delimiter |
CREATE PROCEDURE calcPositionsUpdate(pId INT) BEGIN
    DELETE FROM calcPositions WHERE Id = pId;
    INSERT INTO calcPositions (Id, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16)
    SELECT
    cip.Id,
    SUM((COALESCE(cip.cost, cip.price) * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1)) * cip.modifier * (if(cip.type=0,1,0))) ,
    SUM(cip.modifier * cip.price * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1) * (if(cip.type=0,1,0)))*     ci.modifier ,
    SUM(cip.modifier * cip.priceGross * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1)* (if(cip.type=0,1,0)))*ci.modifier  ,
    COALESCE(SUM(cip.quantity),0)* (if(cip.type=0,1,0)),    
    SUM((COALESCE(cip.cost, cip.price) * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1))* (if(cip.type=1,1,0))) * cip.modifier  ,
    SUM(cip.modifier * cip.price * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1)* (if(cip.type=1,1,0)))*     ci.modifier  ,
    SUM(cip.modifier * cip.priceGross * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1)* (if(cip.type=1,1,0)))*ci.modifier  ,
    COALESCE(SUM(cip.quantity),0)* (if(cip.type=1,1,0)),    
    SUM((COALESCE(cip.cost,cip.price) * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1))* (if(cip.type=2,1,0))) * cip.modifier  ,
    SUM(cip.modifier * cip.price * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1)* (if(cip.type=2,1,0)))*     ci.modifier ,
    SUM(cip.modifier * cip.priceGross * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1)* (if(cip.type=2,1,0)))*ci.modifier  ,
    COALESCE(SUM(cip.quantity),0)* (if(cip.type=2,1,0)),    
    SUM((COALESCE(cip.cost,cip.price) * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1)) * (if(cip.type=3,1,0))) * cip.modifier ,
    SUM(cip.modifier * cip.price * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1) * (if(cip.type=3,1,0)))*     ci.modifier ,
    SUM(cip.modifier * cip.priceGross * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1) * (if(cip.type=3,1,0)))*ci.modifier ,
    COALESCE(SUM(cip.quantity),0)* (if(cip.type=3,1,0))
    FROM
    positions cip
    LEFT JOIN
    customerInvoice ci
    ON
    ci.id = cip.customerInvoiceId
    WHERE
    cip.customerInvoiceId = pCustomerInvoiceId; 
END;
```

Currently for one update of 60 000 rows in "positions" table, and appropriate procedure for every row it takes about 10 hours..

So what do you think, is it possible to improve speed of this actions, and how..

And from your experience, what are Technics for solving this kind of problems..

Thanks in advance.. your time and effort are appreciated..

Comment: while this is a pretty interesting question (+1'd), the term "nice" is very vague. I think a "nice" way of doing it is to rename `calcPositions` to `JohnnyFarts` , for instance. This will cause a 23% efficiency improvement.

Comment: On a slightly more serious note - can you not use Foreign Keys to associate `calcPositions` table data with the `positions` table data?

Comment: You have "redundant" information?  The same value (other than the column you are JOINing on) in both tables?  Not good schema design.